# pip: dependency installation not houring private package server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My Case:
I have a isolated server(without internet and python 3.8.2) which as python virtual env at `/apps/interface/usr/`,
All my wheels are stored in `https://my.private.org/` 
I am using pip 19.2.3 to install the packages.

Now,
I have pacakge named `py`, which has condition like "setup_requires=["setuptools-scm"]," (dependency).

1. `py` package is downloaded from `https://my.private.org/`
2. now, while trying to download `setuptools-scm`, its referring to  `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/...` instead of `https://my.private.org/` 
   I have tried the below methods to redirect the pip to install wheels from `https://my.private.org/` .

Point: The main package is getting installed from my personal repo, But the dependency packages is trying to download from public web which we don't have access to.

Method 1:

```
pip3.8 install py==1.8.1 --index-url https://user:psw@my.private.org/ --extra-index-url https://user:psw@my.private.org/ -v
```

Method 2:
updated /apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/distutils.cfg

```
[easy_install]
find_links = https://user:psw@my.private.org/
index-url = https://user:psw@my.private.org/
```

but no use.

Method 3:
updated below files (tried with each file)

```
/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf
/etc/pip.conf
/root/.pip/pip.conf
/root/.config/pip/pip.conf
/apps/interface/usr/pip.conf
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
raise DistutilsError("Download error for %s: %s"
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Download error for https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/d3/e54f8b4cde0f6fb4f231629f570c1a33ded18515411dee6df6fe363d976f/setuptools_scm-4.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=69258e2eeba5f7ce1ed7a5f109519580fa3578250f8e4d6684859f86d1b15826: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Hoping to find what is the issue.

Note: Below is Error details

```
Downloading from URL https://my.private.org/py/py-1.8.1.tar.gz (from https://my.private.org/py/)
     |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 74kB/s 
  Added py==1.8.1 from https://my.private.org/py/py-1.8.1.tar.gz to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-gohcv4uc'
    Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-install-xp37jgnc/py/setup.py) egg_info for package py
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
        h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/ssl_support.py", line 173, in connect
        sock = socket.create_connection(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 766, in open_url
        return open_with_auth(url, self.opener)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 961, in _socket_timeout
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 1080, in open_with_auth
        fp = opener(request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
        result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/ssl_support.py", line 160, in https_open
        return self.do_open(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1322, in do_open
        raise URLError(err)
    urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-xp37jgnc/py/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-xp37jgnc/py/setup.py", line 5, in main
        setup(
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
        dist = self.package_index.fetch_distribution(
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 655, in fetch_distribution
        dist = find(requirement)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 635, in find
        loc = self.download(dist.location, tmpdir)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 579, in download
        found = self._download_url(scheme.group(1), spec, tmpdir)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 824, in _download_url
        return self._attempt_download(url, filename)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 830, in _attempt_download
        headers = self._download_to(url, filename)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 729, in _download_to
        fp = self.open_url(url)
      File "/apps/interface/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 779, in open_url
        raise DistutilsError("Download error for %s: %s"
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Download error for https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/d3/e54f8b4cde0f6fb4f231629f570c1a33ded18515411dee6df6fe363d976f/setuptools_scm-4.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=69258e2eeba5f7ce1ed7a5f109519580fa3578250f8e4d6684859f86d1b15826: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in /tmp/pip-install-xp37jgnc/py
Removed py==1.8.1 from https://packages.zeomega.org/py/py-1.8.1.tar.gz from build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-gohcv4uc'
Removed build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-gohcv4uc'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `setup_requires` goes through `easy_install` (though on newer versions of setuptools it should go through pip iirc?) -- either way, I'd suggest putting wheels on your pypi server that way you don't build from source every time (avoiding this problem entirely)

Comment: All my wheels are in pypi server(my own pypi). The problem is that it's not looking for pkgs in my server, instead it's trying to look in files.pythonhisted.org which is external server

Comment: well if it's building from source you've either excluded wheels from install or you're missing a wheel for `py`

Comment: its not from source..

Comment: it is, I promise you -- there's no building that happens if it installs from a wheel (if you're not convinced notice it downloads a `.tar.gz` not a `.whl` and then when it fails it says "Removing source")

Comment: the problem i am facing is pointing the easy install to take my packages (tar.gz or .whl) from my server rather than "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/"

Comment: yeah I'm telling you that you cannot, one of the main improvements of pip over easy_install was custom index servers.  but you can avoid easy_install entirely by not building from source

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue,
the easy_install was not honoring index_url configured. Thats main because of the hard coded url in easy_install.py. I changed the url as suggested in below link and its worked fine.
[you can find the anwere here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2385)